# How to make the value attribute of an input element unclearable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes

Example:

When the user is filling the field, I want that the user should not be able to clear or delete the value i.e "Friend". Is it possible to achieve this using CSS or JavaScript?

Comment: use the `readonly` attribute. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you want the value to be Friend plus whatever the user types? And the user not to be able to delete Friend?

Comment: Why not just have Friend as the label?

Comment: Thanks @Haworth, but I want that when the user submits, the data should be stored including "Friend".

Comment: If I add readonly attribute, then how the user can fill the input?

Comment: So just add friend to the data before you send it off.

Comment: So just add Friend to the value before you send it off.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Sure. Anything is possible.

```
input.addEventListener("focusout", () => { 
    input.setAttribute("disabled", "");
});
```

But you should make sure that you're not adversely affecting accessibility or usability.

I think that the `disabled` attribute is more appropriate than `readonly`, as it also conveys some semantics and comes with the benefit of default styling in most browsers.

Comment: If I follow this, then the user will not be able to fill in the input box. My straightforward question is that if a user is filling the input he should not be able to clear the default value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to the input element "onInput" and pass the bellow function to it, like this...

```
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input');
let previousElement = "";
function X (e){
  
  if(e.target.value.length >  previousElement.length){
    previousElement = e.target.value;
    return;
  }else{
    e.target.value = previousElement;
  }
}
inputElement.addEventListener('input', X);
```

This function stores the last input value until the user adds letters, i.e. until the last input's value's length is greater than the current one. But if the user tried to delete letters i.e. current input's value's length is less than the previous input value then this function will replace the current deleted value with the previous value.

Comment: checkout my pen https://codepen.io/tanishka-2000/pen/YzOVLRO?editors=1111, or you are looking for something else.